# Optimizing tiled maps in cocos2d-iphone

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

My cocos2d-iphone game has tiled maps. The tilesets textures are rather big. I got around 5 tilesets and each one is 2048x2048 (retina).

My maps are around 80x80. They have around 8 layers and each one is obviously using one tileset.

The frame rate falls (it goes around 30 sometimes. I know 30 is rather aceptable, but still, I want 50+).

So given that textures are huge I can't afford to make many layers (since each one loads a texture of these).

So how about I divide my tileset textures into much smaller tilesets (like 1024x1024 each)? That will allow me to use many more layers for my maps, right?

Are there any other tips for huge retina display tile maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Texture with 2048x2048 and 32-Bit colors equals 16 MB (!) of memory. Five times that is 80 MB of memory just for the textures. Ouch! For a tilemap that is relatively tiny (80x80) that's an enormous amount of texture memory.

First order of optimization would be to use PVR textures if you really can't reduce the number of tilesets or images within them. You lose some image quality but the memory consumption will go down dramatically, and the rendering performance of PVR textures is a lot better. Of course while working with Tiled you'll have to use the (presumably) PNG texture which you then convert to PVR for use in the project, for example using [TexturePacker](http://www.texturepacker.de).

8 tile layers can be pretty hefty, but depends on how you use them and how many tiles of each layer are actually drawn. Try this: set all but one layer to visible = NO. Then turn the layers back on one by one and see how that affects the framerate.

Finally you should know that Cocos2D's tilemap implementation is utterly inefficient past a certain number of tiles. There have been attempts to improve the tilemap renderer, for example [this one (HKTMXTiledMap)](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/17945) may be worth giving a shot.

Comment: My tilesets are like 3.6 MB. Unless you mean something like... RAM?
I will try the PVR thing and come back later. Thank you.

Comment: RAM = (random access) memory … 3.6 MB is the filesize I assume? That's only relevant for the overall download size of the App but not runtime memory usage.

Comment: One question: how much RAM would it consume for a 2048x2048 texture with 8-Bit colors?

Comment: There is no support for 8-Bit color (ie color palette) textures on iOS. So even if you decrease the color bit depth you'll still have to save it at least as a 16-Bit PNG or PVR. Here's a list of image file formats and their loading times: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/depth-ios-cocos2d-performance-analysis-test-project/#image-formats

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution is simply convert .png files to .pvr.ccz, and both the file size and in memory footprint reduce dramatically. Here are my steps:

1. use TexturePacker to convert tileset files (png files) to pvr.ccz. Make sure it's a 1:1 mapping (same size, no rotation, no border padding, no trim...), and they should be the same size (e.g. 2048 x 2048)
2. open your .tmx file and change the png file path to your pvr.ccz file.

that's it! It works for cocos2d-x in my case. Before the change my game takes 106 MB in memory, and only  ~90MB after the change, and this is only for 1 tileset texture.